# xlrd reading a string as a float

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have the following cell in excel which is a string:

```
72%
```

This is the name of a movie (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3807620/). However, when I import it into xlrd, using:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/david/Desktop/EX.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sh.cell(num,2).value
```

It brings it in as a float:

```
0.72 <type 'float'>
```

How would I bring it in as a string -- that is, force it to evaluate the cell *exactly* as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it possible that when you wrote the cell in excel you didn't check the type of the cell?
if yes the default type is `percentage` and it is probably converted to 0.72
you could try to write the value again and this time check that the cell type is `text`

**update:** I checked in my PC and the cell with `percentage` type gave 0.72 and the cell with `text` type gave 72%.